# integrating javascript with a return from another function

Tags: javascript, forms, return

Here is a form

```
 <cfoutput>
 <form name      = "xrefform" 
    id        = "xrefform"
    action    = ""
    method    = "post" 
    style     = "width:100%; border:0px solid red"
    onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {return false};" 
    onsubmit  = "return submitxref1('#coltop#', '#col#')"> 
 </cfoutput>
```

If submitxref1 returns false, the form should not submit.  However, the action is not indicated because depending on various parameters in the program there can be several actions.  So I use javascript to submit this form:

```
<input 
   type    = "Submit"
   name    = "SubmitXref" 
   class   = "submitbut" 
   value   = "Submit"
   style   = "margin-left: #marl#; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top:20px"
   onclick = "aasubmit('#target#', 'xrefform','#coltop#', '#col#')">
```

Here is the javascript that does the submitting:

```
function aasubmit(target,xsource, coltop, col) {
//xsource" is the form name and the target is the program to submit to
aret = submitxref1(coltop,col);

if(aret == true) {
document.getElementById(xsource).action = target;}
```

This works but is annoyingly inefficient.  The validation function "submitxref1" is called within aasubmit and apparently also from the form tab.  So it runs at least twice.

Since the onsubmit within the form tag apparently triggers running the function submitxref1, I thought that maybe the call to it within aasubmit is redundant.  So I wrote a simpler function:

```
function buttonsubmit(target, source) {
var q = document.getElementById(source);   
q.action = target;
q.submit();
```

This did indeed trigger running the function xref1submit, but although it got to return false, buttonsubmit did not get the message and submitted the form anyway.

Is there code I can add to buttonsubmit to avoid submitting when the return from xrefsubmit is false?

I tried aasubmit and dropping the onsubmit line from the form tag.  The form did not submit, but all the error messages generated by xref1submit disappeared.